# Getting exception while configuring the maven project in jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

Not able to trigger  a successful build using Jenkin.

```
Jenkin Version : 2.46.1
Maven Version :3.5.0
Java version : jdk1.7.0_67
```

I  created one simple project in java on Maven . Now when i integrate this with Jenkin and click on the build now.
Build is failed and getting some exception.

```
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I have attached the  logs detail.

Log Detail:

```
Started by user sougata das Building in workspace C:\Users\sougatadas\workspace\TestNGTutorial Parsing POMs Established TCP socket on 50831 [TestNGTutorial] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java" -cp "C:\Users\sougatadas\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;F:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;F:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main
    F:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0 "C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar" "C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar"
    "C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar"
    50831 <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started Executing
    Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\sougata das\workspace\TestNGTutorial\pom.xml
    install java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
    hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)     at
    hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)  at
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)   at
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)    at
    hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)     at
    hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE  at
    org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:658)
        at
    org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:149)
        at
    org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven33Launcher.java:150)
        at
    org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:127)
        ... 21 more ERROR: Failed to parse POMs java.io.IOException:
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at
    hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:179)     at
    hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)  at
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)   at
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)    at
    hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)     at
    hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at ......remote call to
    Channel to Maven [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java, -cp,
    C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;F:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;F:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging, jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main,
    F:\apache-maven-3.5.0-bin\apache-maven-3.5.0, C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar, C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar,
    C:\Users\sougata
    das\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar,
    50831](Native Method)   at
    hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)  at
    hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:830)  at
    hudson.maven.ProcessCache$MavenProcess.call(ProcessCache.java:161)
        at
    hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:873)
        at
    hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)  at
    hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
        at
    hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405) Caused by:
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException     at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
    hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)     at
    hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)  at
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)   at
    hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)    at
    hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)     at
    hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
    java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
    jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:179)   ...
    14 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at
    org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
        ... 14 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
    DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE  at
    org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:658)
        at
    org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:149)
        at
    org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven33Launcher.java:150)
        at
    org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:127)
        ... 21 more channel stopped Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 10):

The message error `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_USER_SETTINGS_FILE` is followed by issue [JENKINS-43446](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43446), fixed in [Jenkins Maven plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin), [Version 2.16 (June 08, 2017)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin#MavenProjectPlugin-Version2.16(June08,2017)).

That ticket includes the following comment:

> I had to simply specify both a user and global settings file in the "Advanced" portion of the "Build" section.  If I left either of these settings in the default configuration I would get these errors.

As pointed out by [mirabilos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2171120/mirabilos) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555981/getting-exception-while-configuring-the-maven-project-in-jenkins?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment76336812_43601905) and detailed by [Wouter C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619074/wouter-c)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43832242/6309):

> My solution was to set the change the build configuration:
>
> In `Configure > Build > Advanced`:
>
> - Set `Settings file` to `Settings file in filesystem` and enter the path to your settings file. In my case: `/root/.m2/settings.xml`
> - Set `Global Settings file` to `Global settings file on filesystem` and enter the path to your global settings file.
>     I don't have one (I think) so I just set it to `/root/.m2/settings.xml` also.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43832242/2171120 for more details on how to do that.

Comment: @mirabilos Thank you. I have included that reference in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a version 3.3.9 of Maven on Jenkins.

See the bug https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43446

Answer (score 0):

I have Jenkins version 2.60.3. I wanted to use Maven 3.5.0 and got the exact error.

My solution was to upgrade Maven Integration Plugin to 3.1.2.