# Unable to migrate Maven-3.6 due to DEFAULT_GLOBAL_SETTING_FILE error

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2, jenkins-plugins, maven-3

I am upgrading Maven from 3.0 to 3.6 now and during migration, I am facing the issue like InvocationTargetException.  Can anyone why such error and how to solve this?

Environment -
Jenkins-1.x and
Maven-3.6

Tried the proposed fix as mentioned in the article - but no luck.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43446

```
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
hudson.util.IOException2: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:178)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:69)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:328)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:134)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:184)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_GLOBAL_SETTINGS_FILE
at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.settings(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:672)
at org.apache.maven.cli.DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.getMavenExecutionRequest(DefaultMavenExecutionRequestBuilder.java:171)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.getMavenExecutionRequest(Maven31Launcher.java:153)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:130)
... 21 more
```

Comment: Are you running on Hudson ?

Comment: You should probably update your Jekins Version and try some of these if this does not help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555981/getting-exception-while-configuring-the-maven-project-in-jenkins

Comment: Thanks.  I guess too and yes, it is working with Jenkins-2.x.

Comment: @briadeus - But what about its compatibility check with Maven-3.3.9?

Comment: Glad it works, but not sure what you mean with the 3.3.9 compatibility.

Comment: No, tried Jenkins-1.x with maven-3.3.9 also, the same issue.